# Add a "back to blog link" to single.php Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am looking to add a button in the middle of the pagination on my single-post page that will allow the reader to easily get back to the beginning of the blog with one click. I currently have next and previous post. You can view a sample page [here](http://www.sitestyling.ca/abbyphotography/tyler-kaylas-two-eagles-golf-course-wedding/).

The code I presently have added to the single.php is:

```
<div class="pagination clearfix">
    <p class="pagination-next">
         <?php previous_post_link('%link', '< Previous Entry'); ?>
    </p>
    <p class="pagination-prev">
         <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Entry >'); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url('/' . get_option('page_for_posts')) ?>">Back to blog</a>
```

That's probably the link you need. Whether you want to put it in a paragraph tag, or with classes, in-between/before/after the previous and next links is up to you.